# linux recv() function flag parameter?

Tags: linux, function, recv

What will happen if I use `recv(sockfd, buffer, len, 0);` on a non-blocking socket?

If the socket `sockfd` is closed or nothing to be read, does the `recv()` block? (note: the flag in `recv ()` is `0`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the socket is marked non blocking, recv will never block. period.

If the socket is fine but there is no data to be read you will get -1 as return value and errno will be set to EAGAIN.

If there is an error (closed socket etc.), you still get a -1 return value but errno will be set to the appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing to read it will block, if the socket is closed it will return with an error.

See the [recv man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recv.2.html).

Comment: Unless the socket is marked as non blocking, which  he said it is :-)